# Allocating memory to a list stl inside class through user

Tags: c++, stl

```
class Graph
{
    int num;
public:
        Graph(int n)
    {
        num = n;
    }
    list<int>* mylist = new list<int>[num];
    int* arr = new int[num];
    queue<pair < int, int >> pq;
    void accept();
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of vertices=";
    cin >> n;
    Graph g=Graph(n);
    g.accept();

}
```

I have this class of graph and I want to allocate memory of size 'num' which is the input from user in the main function. But it shows bad memory allocation.

Comment: It's not very clear why you want/need dynamic memory allocation for a standard container. One of the main purposes of standard containers is to avoid manual memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about C++'s **initialization**, which is important and different from assignment.

In you example, initialization of `mylist` and `arr` happens before "initialization" of `num` (in fact, you are not initializing `num`, what you do is default-initialize it and then assign to it), hence the value of `num` is indeterminate at that point, and `new` complains "bad memory allocation".

Correct way of initializing members:

```cpp
class Graph
{
    // write data members together,
    // their declaration positions in class do not indicate execution order
    int num;
    list<int>* mylist;
    int* arr;
    queue<pair < int, int >> pq;
    void accept();
public:
    Graph(int n)
      : num(n), mylist(new list<int>[n]), arr(new int[n])
    // member initializer list start with a ":" and followed by a list of
    //   member_name(initializer_for_this_member)
    // note their order should match the declaration order
    {
    // usually initialization all happen in the initializer list,
    // and constructor body is empty
    }

};
```

And as  πάντα ῥεῖ  pointed out, you should avoid using `new` as much as possible and opt for standard container. In you example, I guess you want an dynamic array of list, and a dynamic array of number. You can use `std::vector` for this purpose.

```cpp
class Graph
{
    int num;
    vector<list<int>> mylist;
    vector<int> arr;
    queue<pair < int, int >> pq;
    void accept();
public:
    Graph(int n) : num(n), mylist(n), arr(n) { }
    // initialize vector to contain n value-initialized objects
};
```